# Transfer Array into SQLite and vice versa without looping especially in ActionScript3

Tags: sqlite, actionscript-3, air

I am very new to programming in ActionScript3 and using SQLite. Currently I try to make an AIR application where it will handle from small to large dataset from excel, import into and calculate in AIR using ActionScript3 and stored the calculated data in SQLite.

Right now I have 2 question regarding using array to transfer data into SQLite

**1. Is it possible to INSERT data or UPDATE data in SQLite without using looping?**

In my AIR application, I have an object called `DataInput` in which have 62 variables/properties which will contain 62 different values from 62 columns in excel. I do know that if you create new instance of `DataInput` and push into array e.g `arDataInput` in loop, you can access each of the data in the array using `arDataInput[i].variablename` where i is the index of the array and variablename is the variables/properties of the object.

Obviously, right now I do actually using `for loop` to access the value of each cell in excel then calculate in AIR application before transfer the calculated data into SQLite, row by row within sql transaction.

Is there actually a way to transfer data in array into SQLite (either `INSERT` new row or `UPDATE` existing row) without using loop like `INSERT INTO tblDataInputUW VALUES arDataInput` given that each column name in SQLite table is the same as variables/properties of object within the array eg. SQLite table, `tblDataInput` have column name `namePlat` and array have variables/properties of `arDataInput.namePlat`?

**2. Is it possible to split the data array i got from SQLite into multiple array without looping?**

Right now, I use the following code to extract data from SQLite and stored as an array;

```
txtSQL = new String();
arData = new Array();
txtSQL = "SELECT namePlat, platLat, platLong FROM tblDataInput";
arData = getSQLData(txtSQL);

function getSQLData(text: String): Array
{
    sqlCon.begin();

    sqlStat = new SQLStatement();
    sqlStat.sqlConnection = sqlCon;
    sqlStat.text = text;
    sqlStat.execute();

    sqlCon.commit();

    var result: SQLResult = new SQLResult();
    var arData: Array = new Array();

    result = sqlStat.getResult();

    if (result != null)
    {
        arData = result.data;
    }

    return arData;
}
```

If my assumption are correct, I can access each of the value in `arData` by using `arData[i].variablename` where i is the index of the array and variablename is the table name within the SQLite table `tblDataInput`.

If there are way to split the data in `arData` into 3 different array e.g `arNamePlat` without using looping like `arNamePlat = arData.variablename` because I have many different chart to draw in my AIR application and each chart will have its own array to get value from.

Right now, I actually using different sql statement for different chart like;

```
txtSQL = new String();
arData = new Array();
txtSQL = "SELECT namePlat FROM tblDataInput";
arData = getSQLData(txtSQL);

dgNamePlat.dataProvider = new DataProvider(arData);

txtSQL = new String();
arData = new Array();
txtSQL = "SELECT  platLat, platLong FROM tblDataInput";
arData = getSQLData(txtSQL);

dgPlatLatLong.dataProvider = new DataProvider(arData);
```

I use the same `arData` and `txtSQL` for each chart as I dont store the value anymore after the chart been drawn.

There are actually no restriction for me to just use `for loop`, I asking this question as I don't see any topic regarding on this question and as a self-learning programmer, I like to explore different way of coding and way to incorporate that knowledge into my projects.

Comment: It sounds like you should just be using regular forms. Forms is the lightest and fastest way to send and receive data from the backend. Your app can send an array of objects in a form POST, php or whatever handles the submission, does whatever to database and gives a response to your app. The app waits for the response, consumes it and fires an event. Does that sound like what you need?

Comment: @moot is there any example or tutorial that I can look? I never heard about form before

Answer (score 1):

The best way to send and receive data and do database stuff is through form submissions. AIR can POST regular form submissions like html pages but can also load a response. Regular serverside software like php handles the form submission, does whatever with the database, and returns data or simple success message.

The best way to handle data is to use XML (look into RESTful architecture for reasons why). PHP creates XML for the app. The xml gets loaded and should go into arrays of objects.

Here are some good links to get going on submitting data with forms and reading XML:

republic of code tutorials:

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3contactform/2.php
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xml/

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html
https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestMethod.html